# Как реализовать контроль прохождения маршрута через PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Кратко:

Необходимо проверить, соотвествует ли пройденный машрут транспортом заложенному для него маршруту.

Подробно:

У меня есть две таблицы:

**Таблица с контрольными точками машрута:**

**route_points**:

**id**: идентификатор точки

**route_id**: индентификатор маршрута

**point**: координата контрольной точки

**order_id**: сортировка точек

**Таблица с историей перемещения транспорта:**

**transort_logs:**

**id**: идентификатор лога

**datetime**: дата-время лога

**point**: координаты местоположения транспорта

**transport_id**: идентификатор транспорта

**Я хочу выполнить запрос и получить примерно следующий ответ:**

```
route_point_id (точка маршрута) | match_found (пройдена ли) | time (если пройдена, то во сколько)
                              1 |                      true |                    2020-11-01 13:05
                              2 |                     false |                    null
```

Ниже я прикладываю мое представление о том, как это должно работать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке вы можете видеть:

CP (check point) - точки маршрута из таблицы route_points

L (log) - реальное местоположение транспорта

Для каждого CP нужно сделать Buffer (зону вокруг точки с радиусом, допустим, 30 метров)

Проверить, есть ли точки L, которые входят в эту область

Если есть - сохранить время прохождения точки (если точек в области несколько, то самое первое время)

Я бы хотел иметь один SQL запрос для этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос будет типа такого:

```
SELECT 
   r.id route_point_id,
   min(l.id) NOT NULL AS match_found,
   min(t.datetime) "time"
FROM route_points AS r
   LEFT JOIN transport_logs l ON (ST_DWithin(r.point, l.point, 30))
WHERE r.route_id = <route_id> AND l.id = <transport_log_id>
GROUP BY r.id
```

Если есть несколько точек в радиусе от точки маршрута, то будет выбрана самая первая.

Нужно создать индексы для столбцов `point` в обеих таблицах:

```
CREATE INDEX route_points__point_idx ON route_points USING GIST ( point ); 
CREATE INDEX transport_logs__point_idx ON transport_logs USING GIST ( point );
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сначала не завел ваш запрос, но наводка на ST_DWithin помогла написать свой. Как разобрался - завел и ваш запрос. У меня другая система измерения, поэтому tolerance у меня не 30, а 0.0003. В любом случае - я разобрался, ваш запрос работает, помечаю как правильный ответ.